# Duplicate icons on column splitter in partial rendering

Tags: sxa, presentation

**Environemnt details**: Sitecore 9.0.2 + SXA 1.7.1

**What is happening**: The options to modify the presentation are coming twice, as can be seen in the image below. On hovering over the  icons, message is same  for both.
[image]

**What i have done**: In a fresh instance, i created a partial rendering and added a column splitter to it. Once i moved to one of the newly created columns, i saw this.

Is this a bug? Or if it is something intentional, please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not expected behavior.

Buttons should appear only once.

I think that this is a cache invalidation problem.

If you will clear `SXA[PlaceholderChromeData]` cache, the problem should be gone.

Comment: Can you please help me from where I can clear the cache? I checked at the cache.aspx and the item.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to find it there (`sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`)